# Image circling the window using JApplet

Tags: java, animation, applet, japplet

So here's where I am stuck... I got it to go to the end of the window horizontally, then go down, but I don't know how to make it go left after it reaches the bottom of the window and then go up when it reaches the left side of the screen. 
Thanks,

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class AnimatedImageApplet extends JApplet implements Runnable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Thread t = null;
private Image image;
private int x = 0;
private int y = 0;
private static final int vx = 1;
private static final int vy= 1;
private boolean horizontal = true;
private boolean vertical = true;

public void init() {
    image = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "face.png");
}

public void start() {
    if (t == null) {
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }
}

public void paint(Graphics canvas) {
    canvas.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
    synchronized (this) {
        canvas.drawImage(image, x, y, this);
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    int direction = 1;
    while (true) {
        synchronized (this) {
            x += vx * direction;
            y += vy * (horizontal ? 0 : 1);
            if (x + image.getWidth(this) == getWidth()) {
                horizontal = false;
                direction = 0;
            }
        }
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(15);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have a x/y delta which, when not required, is simply set to `0`, when you reach one of the boundaries (vertical/horizontal) set the other delta to a non 0 value

Comment: I've been staring at this code way too long. So lost, thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, the idea is simple enough.  When you reach one of your edges, you need to change the direction of your movement.

```
if x + image.width > width then go down
else if x < 0 then go up
else if y + image.height > height then go left
else if y < 0 then go right
```

for clock wise motion.

[image: Edge Paint]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class MoveTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MoveTest();
    }

    public MoveTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage img;

        private int xDelta = 2;
        private int yDelta = 0;

        private int x, y = 0;

        public TestPane() {
            try {
                img = ImageIO.read(...);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            Timer timer = new Timer(15, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    x += xDelta;
                    y += yDelta;
                    if (x + img.getWidth() > getWidth()) {
                        x = getWidth() - img.getWidth();
                        xDelta = 0;
                        yDelta = 2;
                    } else if (x < 0) {
                        x = 0;
                        xDelta = 0;
                        yDelta = -2;
                    }
                    if (y + img.getHeight() > getHeight()) {
                        y = getHeight() - img.getHeight();
                        xDelta = -2;
                        yDelta = 0;
                    } else if (y < 0) {
                        y = 0;
                        xDelta = 2;
                        yDelta = 0;
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.drawImage(img, x, y, this);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

You should be careful of threads in Swing as Swing is not thread save.  Have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks. What would I do to click where I want the image to be initially drawn?

Comment: Add a MouseLiistener, when, mouseClicked is called, record the x/y point of the click and then start the Timer